# Discord Bot fail editing msg

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm having issues with this bot, even if runs without errors it still not changing the message, I gave the bot all privildges  and still failing to edit the message

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import settings
from datetime import datetime


class SimpleView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo = None
        self.trabalhando = []

        self.entrar_button = discord.ui.Button(label="Entrar", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="entrar_button")
        self.add_item(self.entrar_button)

        self.sair_button = discord.ui.Button(label="Sair", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id="sair_button")
        self.add_item(self.sair_button)

    async def update_message(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.message.edit(content=f"```Mecânicos trabalhando: \n" + "\n".join([member.display_name for member in self.trabalhando]) + "```")
        

    async def enter_button_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        member = interaction.user
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        self.trabalhando.append(member)
        await self.update_message(interaction)
        

    async def exit_button_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        member = interaction.user
        if member in self.trabalhando:
            self.trabalhando.remove(member)
        await self.update_message(interaction)


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = bot.get_guild(settings.GUILD_ID_INT)
    view = SimpleView()
    message = await guild.get_channel(settings.FEEDBACK_CH).send(view=view)
    await guild.get_channel(settings.FEEDBACK_CH).send("```Mecânicos trabalhando:```")


@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.custom_id.startswith('entrar_button'):
        view = SimpleView()
        await view.enter_button_callback(interaction)
    elif interaction.custom_id.startswith('sair_button'):
        view = SimpleView()
        await view.exit_button_callback(interaction)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Unknown button clicked.", ephemeral=True)


bot.run(settings.DISCORD_API_SECRET, root_logger=True)
````

ok so it suppose to as it runs the bot aways have this 2 buttons
Log in and Log out
and a message below with the list of users and time they loged in and time they loged out
[The way shows on discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECLtE.png)
my plan was to make the buttons and the list who is check in, if you check out you should be removed from the list
and after that have a log message who checked and in and out and time 20 last actions

Comment: What are the errors in your terminal?

Comment: No errors on terminal. Even when I click on the buttons, but looks like when I click on any button it does nothing, only discord tell me interaction fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any reference to the `on_button_click` event in the `discord.py` documentation. Maybe you are trying to use [on_interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_interaction):

````py
view = SimpleView()


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = bot.get_guild(settings.GUILD_ID_INT)
    message = await guild.get_channel(settings.FEEDBACK_CH).send(view=view)
    await guild.get_channel(settings.FEEDBACK_CH).send("```Mecânicos trabalhando:```")


@bot.event
async def on_interaction(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    item_id = interaction.data.get("custom_id")
    if item_id is None:
        return
    if item_id == "entrar_button":
        await view.enter_button_callback(interaction)
    elif item_id == "sair_button":
        await view.exit_button_callback(interaction)
````

> - In order to be able to access and modify the attributes and methods of your `view` object, you cannot override it elsewhere in the code. Use the object as a global variable;
> - Do not use an `else` statement for `item_id`, as the `on_interaction` event will be called for all interactions of your bot. It could be that you are using buttons with views in another part of your bot and they end up being responded to in this event because of `else`;
> - It looks like you are trying to develop a persistent view. See [this example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py) on how to work with persistent views in `discord.py`.

Comment: I do appreciate, the method I was using was from the older version, and was recommended by chatgpt. thanks for the help